# Click Event Not Working After Class Change

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors, click, jquery-events

I have the following script:

```
// dashboard maximize
$('#dashboard-actions .btn-maximize').click(function() {

    // max / restore buttons
    $(this).removeClass('btn-maximize').addClass('btn-restore');
    $(this).find('span').removeClass('icon-maximize').addClass('icon-restore');

    // swap tables
    $('#table-dashboard-actions-mini').hide();
    $('#table-dashboard-actions').show();

    // show form
    $('#form-dashboard-actions-btm').show();

    // restyle panel
    $(this).parents('.panel-dashboard').addClass('panel-dashboard-max');

    // animate panel
    $(this).parents('.panel-dashboard').animate({
            width: "100%",
        }, 250, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    $(this).parents('.panel-primary').animate({
            height: "725px"
        }, 250, function() {
        // Animation complete.
    });

});
```

As you can see, at one point the script changes the class of the clicked button to `.btn-restore`

However this means that I cannot seem to bind an event to `.btn-restore`

I originally had this:

```
// dashboard restore
$('#dashboard-actions .btn-restore').click(function() {

    alert('asdf');
});
```

And the alert statement didn't work, so I changed it to this:

```
$('#dashboard-actions .btn-restore').on('click', function() {
```

But still no joy. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Delegate event, e.g: `$('#dashboard-actions').on('click', ' .btn-restore', function() {...});`. And if you want to remove previously bound event to `.btn-maximize`, delegate this event too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a couple of people have mentioned, event delegation is the key to binding to selectors that don't match yet. The alternative suggestion of binding to the generic selector `.button` that will always exist and then maintaining the state (maximised or restored) in a variable is also valid.

Your issue  with the panel opening and then immediately closing seems to be that you add the `.btn-restore` class inside the event handler immediately. It shouldn't happen, but it seems like the click event is firing again on the new selector (perhaps something to do with `mouseup` and `mousedown` components of the `click` event?). I'd suggest wrapping your `addClass` calls within a `setTimeout()` like so to ensure the classes are changed *after* any events fire, essentially "pushing" the change to the end of the current execution:

```
var $btn = $(this);
setTimeout(function () {
    $btn.removeClass('btn-maximize').addClass('btn-restore');
    $btn.find('span').removeClass('icon-maximize').addClass('icon-restore');
});
```

You'll notice the new variable `$btn`. This is required because `this` inside your `setTimeout` function will no longer refer to the clicked element (a quick search for "javascript scope and this" or similar will explain this further if required). It also doesn't hurt to cache the $(this) result in any case.

Hope that works for you - let me know if I can be of further help.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** as the class changes dynamically.

```
$('#dashboard-actions').on('click','.btn-restore', function() {
```

When you bind the event handler initially, there exists no element with class `btn-restore`, so the click event after class change does not fire.

Also, I see `btn-maximize` being altered, of this is later added/toggled I woould suggest using a single common class like 'btn-toggle' and then add/remove  `btn-maximize/btn-restore`. This would prevent adding two separate event handlers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click','#dashboard-actions .btn-restore', function() {
```

instead of:

```
$('#dashboard-actions .btn-restore').on('click', function() {
```

Delegated events must be bind to something that exist in the dom and in the second part will define the element ('#dashboard-actions .btn-restore') you want to trigger click on.

Comment: `#dashboard-actions` seems static, could be better to bind event at its level but doesn't really matter

Comment: thanks for the tip, and sorry for the late response! that seems to get my `btn-restore` event working, however the results are a little unexpected. Now, whenever the `btn-maximize` event fires, the restore one runs right after it. So basically the panel maximizes and then restores back down straight away. Any why the restore function might be running without me actually clicking the relevant button?

Comment: I've uploaded the page here too if that helps, see how the panel maximizes / restores straight after it — http://www.mattpealing.co.uk/_concept/brdcr/dashboard.html

Answer (score 0):

check the [Jquery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/#entry-examples)

So maybe you need to put something like this.

using the childs element of #dashboard-actions

```
$('#dashboard-actions .button').on('click', function() {})
```

and inside of the function using [hasClass documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

```
$(this).hasClass('className')
```